# How to delete a row for EmbeddedRocksDB table engine in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse, rocksdb

We use regular `insert` for inserting into `EmbeddedRocksDB` tables.

Inserting a new value for a `key` updates the value.

There is no `DELETE FROM rocksTable where xxx` in Clickhouse.

Inserting `NULL` also doesn't work, which just sets default values for the `value` part.

So, how do we delete a row, based on the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete is not implemented.
You can add column (flag) deleted and update it using insert and select only not deleted rows.